# Google Aps Script for Converting Cell Contents into Notes

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Someone shared the following code for converting cell contents into notes in Google sheets. I am attempting to do this...however, not just with one cell but rather a group of cells in a column.  How do I change the "A1" and "B1" in the `targetCell` and `sourceCell` so that the script runs for multiple cells.

```
function addNote() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var targetCell = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var sourceCell = sheet.getRange("B1");

  var noteText = sourceCell.getValue();

  targetCell.setNote(noteText);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried to adapt the script to your needs and a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This function reads the contents of Sheet1 to create notes in Sheet2 and Sheet3

```
function addNote() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  const vs = rg.getDisplayValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i)=>{
    let sht = ss.getSheetByName(r[0]);
    sht.getRange(r[2]).setNote(sht.getRange(r[1]).getValue())
  });
}
```

Sheet1:

| Sheet | Source | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sheet2 | A1 | B1 |
| Sheet2 | A2 | B2 |
| Sheet2 | A3 | B3 |
| Sheet2 | A4 | B4 |
| Sheet2 | A5 | B5 |
| Sheet3 | A1 | B1 |
| Sheet3 | A2 | B2 |
| Sheet3 | A3 | B3 |
| Sheet3 | A4 | B4 |
| Sheet3 | A5 | B5 |

Put your notes in A1 throught A5 in each sheet but you could make the list anyway you want depending upon you needs by simple changing the contents of sheet1

|  |
| --- |
| Note1 |
| Note2 |
| Note3 |
| Note4 |
| Note5 |

Comment: I'm truly sorry as I'm totally new to code and App Script...I have a single sheet (not multiple sheets) where I have content in cells D7 - D107 that I'd like to convert to notes and then make the cells blank again so I can input other information...if that makes sense...thank you again

Comment: The current example could be used on a single sheet.  Of course you would have to add another sheet to serve the function that my Sheet1 provides.  But without any additional information from you I can't help you because you have not shared any real details about what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Recommendation:**

You can try using [setNotes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotesnotes) method like this:

```
function addNotes() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var sourceRange = sheet.getRange("B1:B10").getValues(); //Add the range of the notes (e.g. B1:B10)
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange("A1:A10"); //Add the range of the target rows in a column to put the notes (e.g. A1:A10)

  targetRange.setNotes(sourceRange); //Set multiple notes to a range using .setNotes() method
}
```

**Result**

*Sample sheet:*

[image]

*After running the script:*

[image]

**Note:**

This sample will only work if the source has equal number of rows to the target rows. If you have a more specific goal, please indicate it.

Comment: omg! Perfect!!!!!!! It worked....thank you so very much!

Comment: @MilagrosGonzalez, you're very welcome. You may also up-vote or accept this answer so that other new members of the community, who are looking for the same question, will be able to be recommended to your post and to help reduce their time to post the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Irvin's answer is easily abstracted to work with selections. In this case, selecting a range of cells in any column will write the notes one column to the left.

```
function addNotes() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange()
  var source = range.getValues()
  var target = range.offset(0,-1)
  target.setNotes(source);
}
```